# Can someone explain this strange behavior of R's logical test results?

Tags: r, logical-operators

I have run into seemingly inconsistent results while using different combinations of logical tests in R. Here is a reproducible example:

```
x <- NA
y <- 1

is.na(x) # evaluates to TRUE
x == 2 # evaluates to NA

is.na(y) # evaluates to FALSE
y == 1 # evaluates to TRUE

is.na(x) & is.na(y) # evaluates to FALSE
is.na(x) & y == 1 # evaluates to TRUE
```

The above all evaluate as I would expect them to. The strange part (to me) is below:

```
x == 1 & y == 1 # evaluates to NA
x == 1 & is.na(y) # evaluates to FALSE
x == 1 & y == 0 # evaluates to FALSE
```

I am assuming `x == 1 & y == 1` evaluates to `NA`because `x` is null, which prevents the logical evaluating to `TRUE` or `FALSE`. So, my question is why does changing the logical to `x == 1 & is.na(y)` or `x == 1 & y == 0` actually result in `FALSE`? I would expect the latter two logical tests to result in `NA` as well because `x == 1` can't be `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

Comment: It is documented in `help('&')` : "NA is a valid logical object. Where a component of x or y is NA, the result will be NA if the outcome is ambiguous. In other words NA & TRUE evaluates to NA, but NA & FALSE evaluates to FALSE."

Comment: Thanks for the link to the other post. That clears things up.